# Prevent a Button / Material Button from reserving space for a shadow in a layout

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

See attached screen shot.

[image]

The red TextViews (added for debug purposes) and the three Material design blue buttons are all setup with the same vertical constraint layout setup, but the blue buttons are smaller. I added the red fields just to see if the constraint layout was messing things up. Using the UI viewer I can see that the controls are actually the same size as expected, but there is a margin added to the blue button (the red outline is from the tool). After experimentation and research, I have found this seems to be due to support for the possibility of a shadow around the button. This seems to also apply to regular buttons as well, as I added buttons in the demo as well, with the bottom right "Button1" exhibiting the same behavior. I read that changing the background can cancel this behavior, and doing that in the two other peach "Button1" views got rid of the margin, but also made them visually unresponsive to touch interaction (tapping them did not do the "ripple"). Going down the alley of getting rid of the shadow, I've tried setting the StateListAnimator to null, I've tried setting the OutlineProvider to null and to custom class, I've tried setting elevation and TranslationZ to - as well. (All based on different SO articles). None of these seem to release the margin being reserved while also still letting the button to visually act like a button when clicked.

Any tips on how to programmatically setup a Material Design Button to not reserve a shadow space and still act like a button?

Background:

- Xamarin Android (Xamarin Native, not Xamarin Forms). Don't let that stop you from telling me how to do it in a non-Xamarin C# way, I will translate it back if needed.
- Screens are dynamically driven (so, **created via code** vs layout)
- Screens use ConstraintLayout

Sample code (trimming out the plumbing), though this is really mostly adding user-specified visual settings:

```
        MaterialButton nativeView = new MaterialButton(ctx, null, Resource.Attribute.materialButtonStyle);
        int id = View.GenerateViewId();
        nativeView.Id = id;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        nativeView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
        nativeView.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        nativeView.SetAllCaps(false);
        nativeView.CornerRadius = (int)Math.Round(wdg.Curve * 2.22, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        nativeView.StrokeWidth = 2;
        base.ApplyFontSettings(wdg.FontInfo, nativeView);
        nativeView.StrokeColor = ColorStateList.ValueOf(wdg.BorderColor.Value.ToAndroidColor());
        nativeView.SetBackgroundColor(wdg.FillColor.Value.ToAndroidColor());
        nativeView.SetTextColor(wdg.ForeColor.Value.ToAndroidColor());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A not perfect solution. I have created a sample to test it.

At first, I tried to set the `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` in the xml, but it didn't work. And then I tried to set the margin in the xml, such as:

```
android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
```

The button's shadow space will be covered in both LinearLayout and ConstraintLayout. So I try to set it programmatically：

```
MaterialButton button = this.FindViewById<MaterialButton>(Resource.Id.button1);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
layout.SetMargins(0, -16, 0, -16);
button.LayoutParameters = layout;
```

In the xml, it should be -7 and in the code behind, it should be -16. This can work in the `LinearLayout`, but it didn't work when I changed the `LinearLayout` to `ConstraintLayout`. **So you can put the button in the `LinearLayout` instead of the `ConstraintLayout`.**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. To be clear, I need to wrap the button in a Linear Layout inside the existing constraint layout, and create a negative margin? Is this a bug in the Material Design button, the Constraint layout, or both?

Comment: You can use the LinearLayout replace the ConstraintLayout. Actually, the ConstraintLayout is used for the complex UI and the LinearLayout can fit many UI design. In addition, I have tried to create a native android project with the android studio. The Material Design button's shadow's space can't be hiden in the Constraint layout by all the methods above. So I can't make sure if it's a bug or not. But you can also try to report it on the github. @tcarvin

Comment: I cannot replace the constraint layout with linear layout because the real screens are indeed complex. So my only recourse is to file a bug? I'll take a look at that, thanks!

Comment: But you can't ensure this is a bug in the native android or the xamarin, I can't hide the shadow's space in the native android. @tcarvin